# Modal window doesn't load propper results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have few thumbs on the page which are loaded from mysql database. Now I want to make button view on them and when I click to open modal windows with more info.

The problem is that always is opening first item on each thumb(different id). This is what I've using. I guess the problem is in the button but can't figured out how to fix it.

```
foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM projects ORDER BY project_id") as $row) 
{
     echo '<div class="portfolio-item '.$row['project_category'].'">';
     echo '<div class="portfolio">';
     echo '<a href="#" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio">';
     echo '<img src="'.$row['project_image'].'" alt="Portfolio 1">';
     echo '<div class="portfolio-overlay hvr-rectangle-out">';
     echo '<h2 class="margin-bottom-small">
               <strong class="white-color bold-text"></strong>
           </h2>';
     echo '<div class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolio-4">View More</div>';
            echo '</div><!-- END PORTFOLIO OVERLAY -->
              </a>
           </div>

        <div class="modal fade contact-form" id="portfolio-4" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="portfolio-4" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
                 <div class="modal-body member-info">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                          <figure>
                             <img src="'.$row['project_image'].'" alt="">
                          </figure>
                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                          <div class="description">
                             <h3><strong class="bold-text">'.$row['project_overlay'].'</strong></h3>
                             <div class="light-text">'.$row['project_title'].'</div>
                             <div class="about margin-top-medium">
                                  <p>'.$row['project_details'].'</p>
                             </div>
                          </div> <!-- *** end description *** -->
                       </div> <!-- *** end col-md-7 *** -->
                     </div> <!-- *** end row *** -->
                   </div> <!-- *** end modal-body *** -->
                </div> <!-- *** end modal-content *** -->
          </div> <!-- *** end modal-dialog *** -->
        </div> <!-- *** end Contact Form modal *** -->
      </div> <!-- *** end  portfolio-item *** -->';
 }
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique within a document – and since you are outputting this HTML inside a loop, they of course won’t be.

Comment: Ok, I agree but I can't see how I can make it without loop..

Comment: Learn to separate individual partial problems … Step 1: Write a piece of _static_ HTML code, that does what you want (in regard to the modal functionality) for at least two individual items. Step 2: Write your PHP loop that creates HTML code that is equivalent to your static code written before, only using dynamic values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a simple glance (I can't tell what plugin you are using) I would check this line :  ... div class="modal fade contact-form" id="portfolio-4"
the button triggers this modal data-target="#portfolio-4">

So I would get the index of every row and append it to the id of the modal, then in the button data-target I would also append that index... (so IDs are different) Hope it helps, I did the same but using bootstrap.

Comment: I forget to say that it is Bootstrap also. So can you give me example and are you mean on data-target to enter the id for example `$row['project_id']`?

Comment: yeah also in the button

Comment: But how to change the link in the `data-target`? I mean if I remove `#portfolio-4` it wont open the modal...?

Comment: did you manage to do it? Here is a fiddle that puts the basic skeleton Two modals that can be triggered by the same button, the only thing you need is to add change the data-target attribute in the button (This id should be generated by php, maybe using the index of the array,  so the id is different for modal but sets the target for the button) Hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/clarenswd/kkkzn07j/

Comment: echo '<div class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolio-'.$row['project_id'].'"... and the same for the modal id....  so you will have different ids

Comment: There is only one button on each image which open the modal and it is this `a href` from the code above - `echo '<a href="#" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio">'...` So when I made it like `<a href="#portfolio-'.$row['project_id'].'"..` It still open the first row from database on each modal...

Comment: echo '<div class="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolio-4">View More</div>';

Comment: This echo just open the modal. The actual info/id is on `echo <a href="#" data-lightbox-gallery="portfolio">...`

Comment: then that is what you need man, you will open the respective modal for that button

Comment: Well then something else in this snipped is the problem because as I said above : _So when I made it like <a href="#portfolio-'.$row['project_id'].'".. It still open the first row from database on each modal._

Comment: I made this... I think after this I have to keep working man, hope you get the solution [link] (http://clarenswd.com/bootstrap/modal.php)

Comment: Well .. thank's for this and seems to work with array but I don't know how exactly to write my source with array yet..

Comment: Thank's for the help again. I've made it and it's working good now.